# Replace only strings that are not substrings of similar strings?

Tags: java, string, replace, substring

I have a string, `12999986, 31999999, 39949283, 99002999` in which I am trying to replace all of the patterns `99` with the pattern `00`. However, the pattern cannot be part of a substring of another similar string, say `999` or `9999`. In this example, the output would be `12999986, 31999999, 30049283, 00002999` (`39949283` to `30049283`, `99002999` to `00002999`). I've created this method, but it doesn't really work for larger strings (doesn't find all patterns, inserts strings in random places):

```
public static String replaceAllExact(String data, String searchString, String replacement) {
    List<Integer> locations = new ArrayList<>(); //start (exclusive)
    char[] dataChars = data.toCharArray();
    char[] searchStringChars = searchString.toCharArray();
    char[] replacementChars = replacement.toCharArray();

    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int startIndex = 0; 
    int searchStringCharsLength = searchStringChars.length - 1;

    for(char c : dataChars) {
        if(c != searchStringChars[i] && i == 0) { //not the start of a pattern; continue
            k++;
            continue;
        }else if(c == searchStringChars[i] && i == 0) { //might be the pattern we're looking for
            startIndex = k;
            i++;
        }else if((c == searchStringChars[i] && i > searchStringCharsLength) || ((c != searchStringChars[i] && i < searchStringCharsLength) && i != 0)) { //pattern was too long or too short to be the pattern we're looking for
            i = 0;
        }else if(c == searchStringChars[i] && i < searchStringCharsLength) { //could be the pattern... keep going
            i++;
        }else if(c != searchStringChars[i] && i != 0 && i == searchStringCharsLength) { //this is the pattern we're looking for
            locations.add(startIndex);
            i = 0;
        }

        k++;
    }

    int offset = 0;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(data);

    for(int l : locations) {
        l += offset;
        builder.delete(l, l + searchString.length());
        builder.insert(l, replacementChars);
        offset = (builder.length() - data.length());
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

How can I accomplish this? Regex solutions would be welcome, if they are possible.

**Clarification**

A similar string is a string in which a normal replace will replace some of the characters. For example, using the standard library `replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`, the string `31999999` would be considered similar because `replace(99, 00)` can replace some characters.

The string `39349283` is not a similar string because `replace(99, 00)` cannot replace any characters. The string `39949283` is similar because `replace(99, 00)` can replace some characters.

Comment: Can you explain further? The way I read it now it sounds like you want to replace substrings in your string where your substring is not contained in another substring of your string, which means it will never be replaced-- as a substring is almost always going to be a part of a larger substring given the size permits it. Is it just duplicate characters like in your example?

Comment: I suppose my question is--what constitutes a similar string?

Comment: @EastonBornemeier two consecutive 9s get replaced with two consecutive 0s, but if any more than two are consecutive, he doesn't want them to be replaced.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts but is this supposed to also deal with different patterns other than "99"? what is a similar string to say..."37"?

Comment: @EastonBornemeier oh I missed that. Good question.

Comment: @EastonBornemeier A similar string would be `37373737`.

Comment: @EastonBornemeier I think any pattern in general, dictated by what he sends. So if `searchString = "37"` then I would imagine anything like `3737`, `373737`, etc.... would be considered part of the pattern based on what he described above? But if another string contains `378`, then it wont replace the `37`.

Comment: So by that logic I would say that "999" is not a similar string, as it is not a mere duplication of the previous string. Does that make sense? This definition is very important in fixing this so I want to make sure I understand

Comment: @AlexQuilliam but what about `373`? Is that similar?

Comment: I define a similar string as a string in which a normal replace will replace some of the characters in the string. I'll make an edit to clarify.

Comment: @AndyTurner Since it contains `37`, which is the search pattern, I would be inclined to say yes, but now im not so sure based on what @Easton Bornemeier said.

Comment: If that is your definition of a similar string, then every string contains your substring--per my first comment. See the issue? :)

Comment: See the edit to the question.

Comment: @AlexQuilliam your edit still only addresses searches with a single character repeated, and replacements which are the same length. If this is all you need to handle as inputs, that's fine, but be explicit about these restrictions.

Comment: By your clarification you are never going to replace anything, because you can just take your pattern in the string, add a few characters on each end, and then it is automatically similar because you can find your pattern in the substring. Like in your example: `39949283` has a substring of `3994` which means it is similar, as it contains `99`. All cases match this-- as there if you find a pattern in your string you can find the same pattern in a smaller substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to replace `99` with something else, but only if there is no `9` before or after it.

In that case you can use [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanisms and ensure that

- there is no `9` before, via `(?<!9)`
- there is no `9` after, via `(?!9)`

So you could use `str = str.replaceAll("(?<!9)99(?!9)", "00")`.

Comment: I dont think the question is specific to 99, but a pattern in general.

Comment: @Noobgineer Agree, but solution can be changed easily to be used with other cases. Real solution depends on what OP really wants to achieve.

Comment: @Noobgineer In which case you adjust the regex pattern accordingly.

Comment: Unless OP is using repeating patterns like in the example, I think this depends largely on what the actual problem specification for the "pattern" is and what constitutes the parameters to when it is replaced